# Restricting selectable row of Yii CGridView to checkbox column

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, checkbox, yii

I'm using Yii and I have this **CGridView** here having a **CCheckBoxColumn** as part of the columns defined.

```
this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => $columns
    ),
    'selectableRows'=>2
));
```

Setting the **selectableRows to 2** makes clicking any part of the row  inside the gridview 'check/uncheck' that row too. This is a useful feature so that the user would no longer need to tick the checkbox icon specially if it is very small.

Unfortunately I need to restrict the checkbox ticking to be **toggled only upon clicking the checkbox icon/input element itself** or at least the **column it is in**, and not in any other column of the row. It seems that this feature isn't made yet or won't be and I'm looking somehow to overwrite the Js to achieve this but I don't know where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `'columns'` You should add as first element new array like this:

```
    array(
        'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
        'id'=>'selectableColumn',
        'selectableRows'=>2,
    ),
```

and remove from your array index `'selectableRows'`. This array is configuration of column with checkbox in it. So, basically, you should add to your `$columns`variable array presented above. Here is example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filter' => $model,
   'columns' => array( // <- this is your $columns variable!
        array( // <- just add this array to your $columns var
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'id'=>'selectableColumn',
            'selectableRows'=>2,
        ),
        'columnName1',
        'columnName2',
        ...
   ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite js in your code, see below example for the same:

Code to stop propagation of click event on grid `tr`

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('tr-event-propagation', '$(".grid-view tr").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});');
```

Code of column array to add checkbox in row

```
array(
   'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
   'selectableRows' => null,
   'htmlOptions' => array(
                         'onclick' => 'js: $(this).find("input").trigger("click")'
                    ),
   'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array(
                             'onclick' => 'js: $(this).trigger("click")'
                            ),
   'selectableRows' => 2
),
```

Hope this solution will help you

Note: using `event.stopPropagation();` may breaks other javascript bind with tr or other element of tr

Comment: i have same issue. i applied your solution but it gives me `too much recursion
 

for ( old = elem; cur; cur = cur.parentNode ) {

 ` error. i checked it in console.

Comment: @Jazz you need to check what other event bounded with grid tr

Comment: no other event is binded. but if this issue solved by adding ony `'selectableRows' => 1,` . i don't add other things. it works perfect. is it proper?

Comment: @Jazz I think using 'selectableRows' => 1 you will be able to check one checkbox only

Comment: yes thats also right `selectableRows=>1` only able to check one checkbox. but its strange it also prevent checkbox check on click of `<tr>`.

Comment: @Jazz if you are using event.stopPropagation();, then it will prevent the events of tr

Comment: no i am not using  `event.stopPropagation();`. i only use `selectableRows=>1`.